# Nginx fails to serve media with index.html

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I'm fairly new to Nginx. What I want to achieve is to serve my webpage (with all of its media) with a Docker image of it.

My project's structure:

```
.
├── nginx
│   ├── conf.d
│   └── nginx.conf
└── www
    ├── documents
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── images
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.html
    ├── index.js
    └── resources
```

Note that `conf.d` and `nginx.conf` are yet identical with the default configuration.
I used the following Docker command to start the container:

```
sudo docker run --name nginx \
-p 80:80 \
-v ./www:/usr/share/nginx/html \
-v ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
-d nginx
```

After I navigated to the browser `localhost`, I received my webpage with its style and functionality, but the images and fonts were missing. The browser's console gave me `GET 403` errors, and the Docker logs were:

```
*1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/images/close.svg" failed (13: Permission denied),
 client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: 
"GET /images/close.svg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
...
```

I already checked the file and directory permissions, they were all `-rw-rw-r--`.
I thought the problem might be that I use relative path inside the `index.html` to load the resources, thus I appended the following into the configuration file at `./nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
    location /resources/ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /documents/ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /images/ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

The changes in the configuration haven't brought the solution. Nor when I rewrote the roots like `/usr/share/nginx/html/images`. I would appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.
 According to the documentation, every public directory should have 755 (`rwxr-xr-x`) permission, while the public files 644 (`rw-r--r--`). I changed the permissions and now it works.